# i am unable to view the mysql Data in my table made on php .mysql table primary key intake. 2. I have created 2 php file.first delete.php and delq.php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is the delete page where i want to view the mysql stored data in table but I am unable view. I have created 7 columns for table name registration but I can't fetch the data from database.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="formainsupport"></div>
<div id="forreg">
<?Php

$tbl_name="registration"; // Table name 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("examonline.", $con);

// select record from mysql
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

?> 

<table width="900" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td colspan="8" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>intakeid</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>firstname</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>password</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>confirmpassword</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>homeaddress</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>email</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['intakeid']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['firstname']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['lastname']; ?></td>

<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['password']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['confirmpassword']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['homeaddress']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="delq.php?id=<? echo $rows['intakeid']; ?>">delete</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop
}
?>

</table>

<?php
// close connection;
mysql_close();
?>
```

Here is code for the to delete the data from database. My sql delete query is here but I think it's not working although it's a fine code. I am unable to find the problem.

```
<h1>delq.php</h1>
<?php

$tbl_name="registration"; // Table name
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("examonline.", $con);

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$intakeid=$_GET['intakeid'];

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id

$sql="delete from $tbl_name where intakeid='$intakeid'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
echo "Deleted Successfully";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='Delete.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: First your code is wide open to **SQL Injection** and uses an old library, you should consider using MySQLi or PDO, besides that, change your code from `mysql_query($sql);` to `mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());` and make sure it doesn't throw any errors and if it does, post the error on your question! On your database name you you have an extra DOT `.` remove it `"examonline."` becomes `"examonline"`. You're using `<? ` in some cases and some PHP do not let you use it without turning it on first so you might want to either use `<?=` or `<?php` to make sure it will not give further error

Comment: i am getting error
ERRORYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'intakeid']; ?>'' at line 1

Comment: i modiefied as per your instruction and still the error says..ERRORYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'intakeid']; ?>'' at line 1

Comment: @user3533392 - What do you see if you `echo $sql`?

Comment: @user3533392 and none of the codes you posted have `intakeid` at line 1 so you will have to post the right code. The only line u have with `intakeid` on the above code is `<? echo $rows['intakeid']; ?>` which depending on how your PHP is configure will fail as it will not process it as `<?` alone.